# Java: Different Versions for IE & FireFox

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer, java

How can I install the Java JRE such that I have an older version for IE (specifically 1.4.2) and the latest version for Firefox and the command line?

Note that I have attempted to install both 1.4.2 and 1.6.0 and 1.6.0 seems to override no matter what I do to IE:

1. Disable the Java DLLs via Manage Add-ons
2. Un-install 1.6.0 via Internet Objects
3. Both 1 & 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a looooong time since I've tried anything like this, and you'll have to research the steps to be sure, but something along these lines may allow differing versions of Java to coexist like you want:

- Install the older version as default.  (IE should access this fine.)
- Download the newer version in the SDK+JRE form; install/unzip to your choice of location.
- Setup batch scripts that will change your Java-related environment variables from the older version to the new version temporarily (ie, from one particular shell).
- Setup another batch script to call the first, setting up the environment for new Java, and then startup Firefox.
- Make a shortcut on your desktop that runs that script instead of starting Firefox directly.

Of course, there may be an Easier Way(tm), but that's what occurs off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the folder of the JRE you wish to use under `Program Files` and navigate to it's `bin` directory. Run `javacpl.exe` and go to the "Advanced" tab. Expand "Default Java for Browsers" and check off Microsoft Internet Explorer, then hit OK.

[image]

Comment: that looks like a Much Easier Way(tm).

Comment: With multiple installations of Java, only the most recent shows up on this list, not every version.

Comment: Updated with another possibility

Comment: With multiple installs of the JRE, the single control panel is for all installed versions; there is not a separate control panel for each install. By turning off JRE access to the browser here in the control panel, it disables Java entirely for that browser, not just aparticular version of the JRE.

Comment: This setting does not seem to do anything for me. If I check it in the version of Java I want, it says some changes have been made and I should restart my browser. But if I open the javacpl.exe again it is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

think virtualization, e.g. **[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)** (which allows you to run virtualized applications of Windows guests in seamless mode on the host).

Comment: Isn't this like trying to kill a fly with a shotgun?

Comment: Thank you for the idea, however I am trying to get this to run without virtualization.

Comment: @Oscar great metaphor

Comment: Im with @Oscar, seems a little overkill. Especially with Vbox being an approx. 70mb download now and >100mb install.